# What tools are there for monitoring the django 'locmem' cache?

Tags: django, caching, monitoring

I'm am trying to optimise some caching for a complex django project, which is struggling with a large number of sql queries.

I'm using 'johnny-cache' to simplify the caching of the queries. It invalidates cached entries for a 'model' on 'save' of data to the model, and as such is geared to sites which are mainly read-only.

I have seen a 'memcached' django admin app which i have used in the past, though cannot find it atm. I would really like a way of monitoring django's "locmem" cache backend, does anyone have any suggestions?